# SVG transform circle into simple line

Tags: javascript, css, svg, transform, svg-animate

I'm trying to animate a simple SVG circle (white background or any other color) so that when you hover over it it becomes a simple vertical line (in other words, it sort of flattens into a line) and on mouse out, well, then it animates into a circle again.

Yet I can't find much information on how to approach it... Any and every help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I suppose you could draw an ellipse with the same rx and ry so its a circle and then decrease the ry till it looks like a line.

Comment: also, use a transform to rotate it around the aixs. Also, use a scale on an axis

Comment: @vals would you mind providing an example over here or at a Plunker or Codepen or something. I'm really just learning SVG so I'm not quite sure as to how that would go.

Comment: You won't learn anything if we do that! Read a tutorial, try it and we'll help when you're stuck on some particular point.

Comment: @RobertLongson I'll do that. Your part I looked into and I got it working quite nicely. It does just what I needed it to (thank you very much for that). It's the scale on the axis part that I'm not quite sure of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of the animation using scale

```html
<svg width="500" height="150">
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="40" style="stroke:#006600; fill:#00cc00" >
            <animateTransform 
            attributeName="transform"
            begin="0s"
            dur="2s"
            type="scale"
            from="1 1"
            to="1 0.01"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
        />
</circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I played around with it and finally got just what I needed!